# Layout Edittext Suggestion over Soft Keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

I'm editing suggestion for edittext. I used ContentProvider to get suggestion word.
The currently, How to display the suggestion word as the image in link:

https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/device-2014-06-20-11355.png?_subject_uid=124031547&w=AAAUAbte0hgg4BOYKVR2ztN1FQm_WhX9X06PrWzDOqrQQw

Please, help me!

Comment: can you please post code whatever you have done and your given link is not working.

Comment: Image not found when clicking your link, probably your are not using autocompletetextview? the suggested words on top of the keyboard are the ones provided by the system. I'm not 100% sure but I believe these can't be provided by the developer.